# identify gaps and islands

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I have a database that has the following structure

```
+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| timestamp           | EngOilP_sd | CompOilLVL_sd |
+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| 2015-06-24 20:28:07 |          0 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:30:20 |          1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:36:47 |          1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:41:11 |          1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:43:29 |          1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:45:42 |          0 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:47:51 |          0 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:49:59 |          0 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:52:01 |          0 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:54:17 |          0 |             0 |
+---------------------+------------+---------------+
```

I would like to generate a report like the following:

```
sd             duration      start                    stop
EngOilP_sd     15min 22s     2015-06-24 20:30:20      2015-06-24 20:45:42
CompOilLVL_sd  4min 18s      2015-06-24 20:49:59      2015-06-24 20:54:17
```

I should add that it is not critical that the stop record is the first one where the value = 0, it could be the last record where the value = 1

How might I easily create a well performing query that would give me the information I need? I am using Python for the app, so I would not need the SQL to output the report in this exact form, just get me close with the guts of the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably something more elegant than this, but since you are doing a kind of pivot (transforming from columns to rows, i.e. metadata to data) it is never going to be pretty. Assuming a table like:

```
create table t
( ts timestamp not null
, EngOilP_sd smallint not null
, CompOilLVL_sd smallint not null
) engine = innodb;

insert into t (ts, EngOilP_sd, CompOilLVL_sd)
values 
 ('2015-06-24 20:28:07',0 ,0 )
,('2015-06-24 20:30:20',1 ,0 )
,('2015-06-24 20:36:47',1 ,0 )
,('2015-06-24 20:41:11',1 ,0 )
,('2015-06-24 20:43:29',1 ,0 )
,('2015-06-24 20:45:42',0 ,0 )
,('2015-06-24 20:47:51',0 ,0 )
,('2015-06-24 20:49:59',0 ,1 )
,('2015-06-24 20:52:01',0 ,1 )
,('2015-06-24 20:54:17',0 ,0 );
```

Since we are going to reference the "pivot" several times we create a view for it:

```
create view t_pivot as 
    select 'EngOilP_sd' as sd, ts, EngOilP_sd as val from t 
    union all 
    select 'CompOilLVL_sd', ts, CompOilLVL_sd from t;
```

The start time (using @Pauls comment as the definition) is the earliest time where each attribute is 1:

```
select sd, min(case val when 1 then ts end) as start
from t_pivot     
group by sd
```

The stop time is the earliest time after that where each attribute is 0:

```
select x.sd, x.start, min(case y.val when 0 then y.ts end) as stop
from (
    select sd, min(case val when 1 then ts end) as start
    from t_pivot     
    group by sd 
) as x 
join t_pivot as y
    on x.sd = y.sd
   and y.ts > x.start 
group by x.sd, x.start
```

Adding another level of nesting makes it convenient to determine the duration:

```
select sd, timediff(stop, start) as duration, start, stop 
from ( 
    select x.sd, x.start, min(case y.val when 0 then y.ts end) as stop
    from (
        select sd, min(case val when 1 then ts end) as start
        from t_pivot     
        group by sd 
    ) as x 
    join t_pivot as y
        on x.sd = y.sd
       and y.ts > x.start 
    group by x.sd, x.start 
) as z 
order by sd desc;

+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| sd            | duration | start               | stop                |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| EngOilP_sd    | 00:15:22 | 2015-06-24 20:30:20 | 2015-06-24 20:45:42 |
| CompOilLVL_sd | 00:04:18 | 2015-06-24 20:49:59 | 2015-06-24 20:54:17 |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Awesome. I am still wrapping my head around this, but it's really cool. I asked a modified question at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114748/identify-multiple-gaps-and-islands regarding how I could identify n islands.