# identify multiple gaps and islands for n columns

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

In this [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112178/identify-gaps-and-islands), I asked for a way of identifying some gaps and islands. with a table `t` below;

```
+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| ts                  | EngOilP_sd | CompOilLVL_sd |
+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| 2015-06-24 20:28:07 |          0 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:30:20 |          1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:36:47 |          1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:41:11 |          1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:43:29 |          1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:45:42 |          0 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:47:51 |          0 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:49:59 |          0 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:52:01 |          0 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:54:17 |          0 |             0 |
+---------------------+------------+---------------+
```

The following view will give me the islands of data where values are successively `true`;

```
create view t_pivot as
    select 'EngOilP_sd' as sd, ts, EngOilP_sd as val from t
    union all
    select 'CompOilLVL_sd', ts, CompOilLVL_sd from t;

# explain
select sd, timediff(stop, start) as duration, start, stop
from (
    select x.sd, x.start, min(case y.val when 0 then y.ts end) as stop
    from (
        select sd, min(case val when 1 then ts end) as start
        from t_pivot
        group by sd
    ) as x
    join t_pivot as y
        on x.sd = y.sd
       and y.ts > x.start
    group by x.sd, x.start
) as z
order by sd desc;
```

Gives

```
+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| sd            | duration | start               | stop                |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| EngOilP_sd    | 00:15:22 | 2015-06-24 20:30:20 | 2015-06-24 20:45:42 |
| CompOilLVL_sd | 00:04:18 | 2015-06-24 20:49:59 | 2015-06-24 20:54:17 |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Now,** I am stumped as how to look at the following table for n gaps

```
+---------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| ts                  | EngOilP_sd | CompOilLVL_sd | Brake_sd      |
+---------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2015-06-24 20:28:07 |          0 |             0 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:30:20 |          1 |             0 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:36:47 |          1 |             1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:41:11 |          1 |             1 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:43:29 |          1 |             1 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:45:42 |          1 |             0 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:47:51 |          0 |             0 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:49:59 |          0 |             1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:52:01 |          1 |             1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:53:01 |          1 |             1 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 20:54:01 |          1 |             1 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:56:01 |          1 |             1 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:57:01 |          1 |             1 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 20:58:01 |          1 |             1 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 21:02:01 |          1 |             1 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 21:32:01 |          0 |             1 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 21:52:01 |          0 |             0 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 22:12:01 |          0 |             0 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 22:20:01 |          0 |             0 |             0 |
| 2015-06-24 22:49:01 |          0 |             1 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 23:52:01 |          0 |             1 |             1 |
| 2015-06-24 23:54:17 |          0 |             0 |             0 |
+---------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The result set I am looking for here would be as below

```
+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| sd            | duration | start               | stop                |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| EngOilP_sd    | 00:15:22 | 2015-06-24 20:30:20 | 2015-06-24 20:45:42 |
| EngOilP_sd    | 00:10:00 | 2015-06-24 20:52:20 | 2015-06-24 21:02:42 |
| CompOilLVL_sd | 00:06:42 | 2015-06-24 20:36:47 | 2015-06-24 20:43:29 |
| CompOilLVL_sd | 00:42:02 | 2015-06-24 20:49:59 | 2015-06-24 21:32:01 |
| CompOilLVL_sd | 00:03:00 | 2015-06-24 20:49:59 | 2015-06-24 20:54:17 |
| Brake_sd      | 00:06:40 | 2015-06-24 20:41:11 | 2015-06-24 20:47:51 |
| Brake_sd      | 00:58:01 | 2015-06-24 20:54:01 | 2015-06-24 21:52:01 |
| Brake_sd      | 01:02:00 | 2015-06-24 22:49:01 | 2015-06-24 23:52:01 |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT** Initially, I did not have the column `Brake_sd` in the question. User @tombom's answer correctly describes the case where the `Brake_sd` column is not present, although that is the only difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`ts` varchar(19), `EngOilP_sd` int, `CompOilLVL_sd` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`ts`, `EngOilP_sd`, `CompOilLVL_sd`)
VALUES
    ('2015-06-24 20:28:07', 0, 0),
    ('2015-06-24 20:30:20', 1, 0),
    ('2015-06-24 20:36:47', 1, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 20:41:11', 1, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 20:43:29', 1, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 20:45:42', 1, 0),
    ('2015-06-24 20:47:51', 0, 0),
    ('2015-06-24 20:49:59', 0, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 20:52:01', 1, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 20:53:01', 1, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 20:54:01', 1, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 20:56:01', 1, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 20:57:01', 1, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 20:58:01', 1, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 21:02:01', 1, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 21:32:01', 0, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 21:52:01', 0, 0),
    ('2015-06-24 22:12:01', 0, 0),
    ('2015-06-24 22:20:01', 0, 0),
    ('2015-06-24 22:49:01', 0, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 23:52:01', 0, 1),
    ('2015-06-24 23:54:17', 0, 0)
;

create view t_pivot as
    select 'EngOilP_sd' as sd, ts, EngOilP_sd as val from t
    union all
    select 'CompOilLVL_sd', ts, CompOilLVL_sd from t;
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT sd, TIMEDIFF(MAX(ts), MIN(ts)) AS duration, MIN(ts) AS startime, MAX(ts) AS endtime
FROM (
    SELECT 
    tp.*
    , @val_change := IF(@prev_val != tp.val, @val_change + 1, @val_change) AS vc
    , @prev_val := tp.val
    FROM
    t_pivot tp
    , (SELECT @prev_val := NULL, @val_change := 0) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY sd, ts
) sq
WHERE val = 1
GROUP BY sd, vc;
```

**Result:**

```
|            sd |                  duration |            startime |             endtime |
|---------------|---------------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| CompOilLVL_sd | January, 01 1970 00:06:42 | 2015-06-24 20:36:47 | 2015-06-24 20:43:29 |
| CompOilLVL_sd | January, 01 1970 00:42:02 | 2015-06-24 20:49:59 | 2015-06-24 21:32:01 |
| CompOilLVL_sd | January, 01 1970 01:03:00 | 2015-06-24 22:49:01 | 2015-06-24 23:52:01 |
|    EngOilP_sd | January, 01 1970 00:15:22 | 2015-06-24 20:30:20 | 2015-06-24 20:45:42 |
|    EngOilP_sd | January, 01 1970 00:10:00 | 2015-06-24 20:52:01 | 2015-06-24 21:02:01 |
```

- See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60db9/8/0)

**Explanation:**

With the subquery in the `FROM` clause we are initializing our variables. The `ORDER BY` is very important! Here's why: In the `SELECT` clause each line is processed. The order in the `SELECT` clause is also important. Here

```
, @val_change := IF(@prev_val != tp.val, @val_change + 1, @val_change) AS vc
```

we increment our variable `@val_change` if the value in the column `val` differs from the "previous" row (that's why `ORDER BY` is so important). The "previous row" is in the variable `@prev_val`. The value of the current row is assigned to it in this line

```
, @prev_val := tp.val
```

Since MySQL processes each line in the `SELECT` clause in the order the `SELECT` clause is written, the `@prev_val` variable holds the value of the previous row (or NULL when no row has been processed yet) in the previous line of the `SELECT` clause.

Now all we have to do is `GROUP BY` sd and this `@val_change` variable in the outer query.

- Read more about how to use user-defined variables in the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html).

**CAVEAT:**

This will result in a full table scan.

*sorry for bad english, hope it's understandable*

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

The query still is the same. You just have to adjust the view `t_pivot`

```
create view t_pivot as
    select 'EngOilP_sd' as sd, ts, EngOilP_sd as val from t
    union all
    select 'CompOilLVL_sd', ts, CompOilLVL_sd from t
    union all
    select 'Brake_sd', ts, Brake_sd from t;
```

to include `Brake_sd`.

- See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8d6af/1/0)